# Ionic Storage get doesn't work until reloading page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, promise, storage

I'm trying to 'get' an Array from the storage, save it to `MaschinenArray` and generate an ion-list. My only problem with this is, that I have to reload the page after the "ionic serve" command one time, else it says `Maschinen = null` as an example.

I thought it might be a problem if this function is async and the HTML will be loaded before, but if I trigger the Event later via a button it still says `null`.

I inititalize the Array above the constructor:

```
export class MaschinenParkPage {
maschinenArray : Maschine[] = [];

constructor(private menu: MenuController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage) {


    this.storage.get('maschinen').then((buffer) => {

        this.maschinenArray = buffer;
    });
```

Any ideas? Or is the constructor maybe the wrong spot to initialize some variables?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: you need to wait for storage.ready before fetching stuff

Comment: doesn't help, i tried this already out

Comment: ok. pity. But still, you need to code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to declare that array?

If you have stored it correctly in the storage you can retrieve a object array as,

```
export class MaschinenParkPage {
maschinenArray : any;

constructor(private menu: MenuController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage) {


    this.storage.get('maschinen').then((buffer) => {

        this.maschinenArray = buffer;
        console.log(this.maschinenArray);
    });
```

I have already written something like this in my code already and works perfectly fine. 
You can go to chrome inspect (press the combination Ctrl+Shift+I) and check console.log

Update:
Also go to chrome inspect -> Application tab -> IndexedDB to find 'maschinen' storage. Check it.

Comment: That didn't help sadly. To be clear: If call the page: MaschineParkPage and I click for example a button that logs in the console the Array, then it says 'null'. If i try to add an object, i get the error: cannot read property 'push' of null. It just seems like the Array isn't initalized until i click F5 one time and everything works...

Comment: There is no "Maschinen" storage in indexeddb. But in _ionickv in the Web SQL section ,where I found my MaschinenArray entries.

Comment: @felix9607 yeah its on the _ionickv and check my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah now I remember the problem I guess. I had a similar issue where I wanted to login and and display data according to login details.

1. First I used location.reload(); that reloads whole app after login which is not nice.
2. Then I found [Events from ionic angular](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) which solved my problem. you can try this. 
   sample code is,

in my sidebar controller where I subscribe it

```
  this.events.subscribe('user:login', () => {
      this.ngOnInit();
    });
```

in my login controller

```
this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.set('loginData', response).then(()=>{
        this.events.publish('user:login');
      });
    });
```

according to my code i retrieve data from storage in ngOnInit.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to try this out! Thanks for your help so far

Comment: location.reload() kills sqlite cordova plugin. I suggest not using it (if you still do)

Comment: @TomG now I'm using Events not location.reload()